# Why such setup does not record anything for Trace Viewer Playwright?

Tags: playwright, playwright-java

Why such setup does not record anything for Trace Viewer Playwright?
I'm trying to record files for Playwright Trace Viewer but after running:

```
mvn exec:java -e -D exec.mainClass=com.microsoft.playwright.CLI -D exec.args="show-trace trace.zip"
```

trace is empty. Am I doing something wrong?
This is an example test setup which I'm using:

```
public class TestSearchPage {

    static Playwright playwright;
    static Browser browser;

    BrowserContext context;

    @BeforeAll
    static void launchBrowser() {
        playwright = Playwright.create();
        browser = playwright.chromium().launch(new BrowserType.LaunchOptions()
                .setHeadless(false)
                .setSlowMo(500));
    }

    @AfterAll
    static void closeBrowser() {
        playwright.close();
    }

    @BeforeEach
    void createContextAndPage() {
        context = browser.newContext();
        context.tracing().start(new Tracing.StartOptions()
                .setScreenshots(true)
                .setSnapshots(true)
                .setSources(true)
        );

        //page = context.newPage();
    }

    @AfterEach
    void closeContext() {        
        context.tracing().stop(new Tracing.StopOptions()
                .setPath(Paths.get("trace.zip")));        
        context.close();
    }

    @Test
    void shouldSearch() throws InterruptedException {

        Page page = browser.newPage();
        SearchPage searchPage = new SearchPage(page);
        searchPage.navigate();
        ...      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake: instead of browser.newPage()
should be

```
Page page = context.newPage();
...
```